# Can we have 2 phase power supply?

Tags: electricity

Can I have a 2 phase power supply line with the phases separated by 180 degrees? I heard it is there with 90 degree phase apart with an active return path.

GL

Comment: See [Split-phase electric power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-phase_electric_power) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_electric_power

Comment: Theoretically they are possible, but designing an armature that handles this type of system would be difficult. Basically because 'the other side' of the first phase would be placed at exactly $180^0$ from the start of the first phase. Therefore the second phase cannot possible start from there.

Comment: The residential AC power in the USA is 2-phase at 180 degrees, 120+120=240. I use a 2:1 step down transformer to get a 2-phase power with the normal 120 voltage.

Comment: @safesphere, 3 phase current is transmitted in the U.S., and the wires carrying this current are split such that each neighborhood takes current off of only one wire of the three.  The transformers in each neighborhood are wired on their secondary (the step down part of the transformer) such that the circuit breaker box can use half the wire turns from the transformer (120 V) or all the turns from the transformer (240 V).  This means that each house uses single phase A/C current.

Comment: @DavidWhite Thanks for your clarification. So a single phase is split into two by a balanced transformer. Its output is two phases at 180 degrees to each other. I know that this is commonly called "one phase", which is self evidently wrong, but thanks for your explanation of the likely reasons for this wide spread misconception.

Comment: @safesphere, the single phase to an individual house isn't split into two.  There is only a single phase going to each house.  The step down part of the transformer that controls the current to each house allows for either 120V or 240V, but both voltages are in phase with each other, and both voltages are single phase.

Comment: @DavidWhite I have 3 wires coming to my house in Kansas. One is the neutral connected to the ground. The other two are 120V each. The voltage between them is 240V, so they are out of phase. There is no line with 240V relative to the neutral. There are no 120V and 240V lines that are in phase. So my supply is two-phase that works great for my projects. I don't know of course how your power is configured.

Comment: @safesphere, see http://www.oempanels.com/240v-single-phase-and-240v-3-phase

Comment: @DavidWhite Yes, the first diagram clearly shows that the "Line 1 to Neutral" and "Line 2 to Neutral" voltages are out of phase with each other and thus represent a two-phase 180-degree supply with 240V between the phases. If Line 1 and Line 2 were in phase, the voltage between them would be zero. Thanks for proving my point that the "one-phase" label is a wide spread misconception. I rest my case, because comments on this site are not for extended discussions. Good talk!

Comment: @DavidWhite - Funny, I have two phase power to my house. Full three phase is available, but costlier. 208 2-phase uses any two legs of a 480 3-phase service, without referencing to neutral. It is often used for HVAC systems in residential service.

Comment: @safesphere, the picture clearly states "single phase, 3 wire".  The transformer secondary winding shown in the top drawing is clearly a single phase winding.  However, you obviously have your mind firmly made up.

Comment: @JonCuster, I never meant to say that it was impossible to send 2 phase power to a residence ... I stated that the common arrangement is what is shown in the link that I posted.

Comment: @JonCuster If you measure your voltages against the neutral, they would be at 120 degrees to each other, because they are two phases of a three-phase supply. I guess, the technical jargon may call this "a two-phase supply", but obviously in a true two-phase supply the phases would be at 180 degrees to each other when measured against the neutral. One phase is easily converted to two (at 180) by a balanced transformer. Too bad people just read jargon labels without thinking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly you can have any number of phases with any phase angle between them.

Most power plants produce three phase power with the phases separated by 120 degrees because that is the minimum number of conductors configuration for which the power is constant over one cycle. Having constant power reduces mechanical vibration and improves the lifetime of the generator.

Comment: For a 90° diphased alternator, you would have $P=U\cos (\omega t)I\cos (\omega t-\varphi )+U\cos (\omega t-\pi /2)I\cos (\omega t-\varphi -\pi /2)$ or $P=UI\cos (\varphi )=2{{U}_{e}}{{I}_{e}}\cos (\varphi )$ which is a constant power ?.
But the total current is not zero as for 3 phases separated by 120°.

Comment: An AC supply with 90 degrees phase between current and voltage has ZERO real power, though it has non-zero reactive power (which is what your formulas are describing). The plots of power against time for each phase of a 2-phase system are identical, and they are also identical to the plot for a single-phase system. This is not the case for any number of phases greater than 2.